# IM Support for users in multiple Active Directory domains using LDAP solution

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cross-domain, multiple-domains

Does this application support cross domain authentication, allowing users from different Active Directory domains to communicate with each other using the LDAP solution with single-signon?

Comment: What do you mean by "this application"?

Comment: Currently using Openfire Spark for users as an Instant Messenger client application.  But it doesn't support cross domain authentication using LDAP as the solution.  Was told that ejabberd provides that type of functionality that we're looking for...to support users across multiple domains in a forest

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask